# issue collecting output from cmd

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, data-manipulation

I'm trying to automate something that is dependent on the model of the machine and it's checked using its serial number.

Currently, I'm trying to find a way to get the serial number and save it so that I can automate inputting it in the search bar (dell websites Identify your product)

```
wmic bios get serialnumber >C:/test.txt
```

When I try running this nothing appears in the test.txt file

```py
import os
os.system ('start cmd /k "wmic bios get serialnumber"')
```

When I try running this it returns
"
SerialNumber
abc123
"
I'm just not sure how to store that information for later use.

Comment: You start a `cmd` instance and try to execute a program named `{"wmic bios get serialnumber"}`? That doesn't even work directly from cmd. On command line try `start cmd /k {"wmic bios get serialnumber"}` and `start cmd /k wmic bios get serialnumber` and `start cmd /k "wmic bios get serialnumber"`. `cmd /?``  tells you about the quotes.

Comment: I just checked I added some extra {} that caused the issue.    When I used os.system ('start cmd /k "wmic bios get serialnumber"') the serial number worked. I just don't know how to save that information

Comment: I'm not even sure that you need to include `cmd.exe` at all. Have you tried: ```import subprocess```, followed by either ```subprocess.Call('wmic.exe /Output:"C:\test.txt" BIOS Get SerialNumber')``` or ```subprocess.Call('wmic.exe /Output:"C:\\test.txt" BIOS Get SerialNumber')```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Final code (in terms of my question)

```py
import os
os.system('start cmd /k "wmic bios get serialnumber >C:\\Users\\Batman is better than Superman\\Desktop\\test.txt"')
```

So it's worth noting that for the file path to work you have to use \\ as you would get the syntax error below. I also had to include the file path in the single quotes not after the closed Parentheses.

(SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 44-45: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape)

I also found out (using pycharm /selenium for the later steps of this code) that if you put the file path as (r'C:\blahblah) it works but I got a deprication error. Below is a sample of what I did to get past the Deprecation warning

```py
serv = Service(r"C:\Users\BatMan\PycharmProjects\DellUpdate\Drivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=serv)
```